# Why does range equality not work in a guard?

Tags: elixir, pattern-matching

I want to write a function that will, given a range and a value, n, check if the range spans exactly `n..n`. My first attempt looked something like this, but does not have the expected behavior (note the first return value is `false`)

```elixir
defmodule Range do
  def equal?(n, range) when range == n..n, do: true
  def equal?(n, range), do: false
end

IO.puts(Range.equal?(1, 1..1)) # false
IO.puts(Range.equal?(1, 1..5)) # false
```

However, if I shift the approach to use pattern matching on the `range` argument, I can produce a function that works.

```elixir
defmodule Range do
  def equal?(n, n..n), do: true
  def equal?(n, range), do: false
end

IO.puts(Range.equal?(1, 1..1)) # true 
IO.puts(Range.equal?(1, 1..5)) # false
```

Looking at the two, it's not clear to me why they are not equivalent. If I replace the `when range == n..n` with `when range == 1..1` this works as expected (obviously only for n = 1).

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like an Elixir bug. Can reproduce with [`match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) too: `match?({n, n..n}, {1, 1..1})` -> `true`, `match?({n, range} when n..n == range, {1, 1..1})` => `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) core.

Within regular context, unless explicitly specified via `//step`, the `step` for the `Range` struct is explicitly set to `1`, while inside a guard it’s set to `nil`: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.4/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3805-L3818

```elixir
defmodule R do
  def equal1?(n, range) when range == %Range{first: n, last: n, step: 1}, do: true
  def equal1?(_n, _range), do: false

  def equal2?(n, range) when range == n..n//1, do: true
  def equal2?(_n, _range), do: false
  
  def equal3?(n, range) when range == n..n, do: true
  def equal3?(_n, _range), do: false
end

iex||1 ▸ R.equal1? 1, 1..1
true
iex||2 ▸ R.equal2? 1, 1..1
true
iex||3 ▸ R.equal3? 1, 1..1
false
```

<del>I’m going to provide a pull request fixing this, thanks for reporting.</del>

Unfortunately, for dynamic `first` and `last` values there is no way to infer a proper step (while it’s still possible for same values, or one might blindly infer `1`, both solutions are incomplete and hacky.)

**That said, please use a well-formed modern range with a step `n..n//1` to make it work in guards as expected.**

Comment: Why is inferring 1 incomplete? In a non-guard context, that's the behavior, so I'm not sure I get what's different here.

Comment: No, in a non-guard context, that's not the behavior. The behaviour is inferring `1` for `first < last` and `-1` otherwise, as it might be seen in the code I linked. `4..3` has to have a step `-1` and in a dynamic context, it’s impossible to resolve.

Comment: Looks like a fix was implemented, which I imagine will be in the next release. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/8de8ca49c367f700425dc94d42a558bcb5736a10

Comment: Wow. The fix is smart, I failed to figure it out. José applied the fix 5 hours ago, that’s why it makes a lot of sense to post such questions here.